# Calculating Best Linear Predictor: vector transposed translated into non-transposed vector?

Tags: regression, expected-value, vector

I am studying the best linear predictor part of Conditional Expectation and the Projection part about the regression model.

while we are looking for the Beta that minimizes S(B), I quite do not understand how the first function can be written in the second one:

S(B) = E[(Y-X'B)^2]    - first
S(B) = E[Y^2] -2B'E[XY]+B'E[XX']B            -second

' refers to transpose.
For example, I dont understand why we have B' and X in the second one which was absent in the first one. I guess there is some manipulation or traits of expectation that I am missing.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to CV. This is a MathJax enabled site. Please use this to typeset your mathematical expressions. For a quick guide, please check [Instructions on how to use LaTeX on CrossValidated](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1604/instructions-on-how-to-use-latex-on-crossvalidated).